# How can I find the next entry in a table after an entry in a different table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I think I'm just running into an issue where I can't wrap my brain around the problem, but I'm also not sure if it's actually possible.

I have two tables.  One is a transaction log.  The other is an item history.  I need to know if a transaction happened while an item process status was set, so that I can count all transactions where that property wasn't set.

A simplified view of the relevant columns in the tables:

transactions:

```
event_id
event_type
event_item_id
event_timestamp
```

item_history:

```
item_id
item_process_status
item_history_timestamp
```

What I need to do is count all `event_type IN ('71', '72, '74)` events, where the `event_item_id`'s next entry (i.e. `item_history_timestamp` is the first `item_history` entry for `item_id` after `event_timestamp`) does not have an `item_process_status`.  I *think* I should be using LEAD, or OVER, or some other analytic funcion, but I'm not nearly familiar enough with the analytics functions to know how I could construct such a query.  The only time I've used them in the past was on a single table.

Sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
  item_id VARCHAR(5),
  item_process_status VARCHAR(2)

CREATE TABLE item_history (
  item_id VARCHAR(5),
  item_process_status VARCHAR(2),
  item_history_timestamp TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE event (
  event_id VARCHAR(5),
  event_type VARCHAR(2),
  event_item_id VARCHAR(5),
  event_timestamp TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO item VALUES('10233', 'IP');
INSERT INTO item VALUES('40421', NULL);
INSERT INTO item VALUES('44026', NULL);
INSERT INTO item VALUES('55329', NULL);

INSERT INTO item_history VALUES('55329', NULL, TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-02 13:37', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO item_history VALUES('40421', NULL, TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-02 15:44', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO item_history VALUES('10233', 'OR', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-03 08:21', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO item_history VALUES('10233', 'IP', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-03 09:15', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO item_history VALUES('44026', NULL, TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-04 16:28', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO item_history VALUES('44026', 'IP', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-05 11:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO item_history VALUES('40421', NULL, TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-06 10:03', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO item_history VALUES('10233', NULL, TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-06 14:19', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO item_history VALUES('55329', 'IP', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-07 08:36', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO item_history VALUES('10233', NULL, TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-08 12:52', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO item_history VALUES('44026', NULL, TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-09 11:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));

INSERT INTO event VALUES ('00001', '71', '55329', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-02 13:44', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('00002', '69', '40421', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-03 17:23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('00003', '43', '10233', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-03 22:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('00004', '52', '44026', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-04 19:12', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('00005', '72', '10233', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-04 20:32', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('00006', '74', '40421', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-05 17:06', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('00007', '71', '44026', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-06 11:09', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('00008', '80', '10233', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-06 16:29', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('00009', '71', '55329', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-07 13:44', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('00010', '69', '40421', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-07 17:23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('00011', '43', '10233', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-07 22:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('00012', '52', '44026', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-08 19:12', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('00013', '72', '10233', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-08 20:32', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('00014', '74', '40421', TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-09 17:06', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
```

Expected query output:
    event_id | count(*)
    71       | 2
    72       | 1
    74       | 2

The trick here is that the first 71 (event 00001) isn't counted because item 55329 has process status in the next item history entry, event 00013 doesn't count because the item currently has a process status and it happened after the last transaction for item 10233.

Note that this doesn't work with SQLfiddle, because the site doesn't have a TO_TIMESTAMP function apparently.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output, best on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: The other advantage to providing sample data and expected output on SQLFiddle is that by the time you put all that in you've got everything you need to figure out how to solve the problem yourself - in which case you can post an answer to your own question and accept it - and you'll probably pick up some upvotes for solving it yourself.  :-)  Share and enjoy.

Comment: It does: [Your example at SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b34c) I suppose you forgot to change to Oracle from, default, MySQL at SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, build full status history for items:

```
  select
    item_id,
    (
      lag(until_time) over (
        partition by item_id 
        order by until_time
      )
    ) since_time,
    until_time,
    item_process_status
  from (
        select 
          item_id, 
          item_history_timestamp until_time,
          item_process_status
        from 
          item_history
      union all
        select 
          item_id,
          systimestamp until_time,
          item_process_status
        from item
  )
```

Then join it with events history to get transactions which happened for each slice of status history and apply filters:

```
  select
    full_history.item_id,
    full_history.since_time,
    full_history.until_time, 
    full_history.item_process_status,
    item_events.event_type,
    item_events.event_timestamp,
    item_events.event_id
  from 
    (
      select
        item_id,
        (
          lag(until_time) over (
            partition by item_id 
            order by until_time
          )
        ) since_time,
        until_time,
        item_process_status
      from (
          select 
            item_id, 
            item_history_timestamp until_time,
            item_process_status
          from 
            item_history
        union all
          select 
            item_id,
            systimestamp           until_time,
            item_process_status
          from 
            item
      )
    )
          full_history,
    event item_events
  where
    item_events.event_item_id = full_history.item_id
    and
    item_events.event_timestamp < full_history.until_time
    and
    (
      item_events.event_timestamp >= full_history.since_time
      or
      (full_history.since_time is null)
    )
    and 
    item_events.event_type in ('71','72','74') 
    and
    (full_history.item_process_status is null)
```

[**<kbd>SQLFiddle exmaple</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b34c/22)

Comment: Yikes! That did the trick. I actually added another wrapper to roll that into monthly totals, but that didn't change it much.